# playing with SharePoint 2013 Lists Views and Schema

Tags: list, listview, sharepoint-2013

need to know how to get SharePoint List specific View among my Custom List Views or to modify a SharePoint List Schema... I explain :

Before i start i need to tell you that my need here is to have a list exactly like Discussion Board List just i need to modify its New/Edit forms. So i have 2 important creterias that i need to have :

1/Ii need to be able to acess the `schema.xml` file to add my custom New/edit forms to the list

2/ Or i need to be able to get the default View of Discussion Board List (the one with reply button and like etc...)

So, here are my Problems:

- If i create a custom list (from Visual Studio) and i make it based on Discussion Content Type, Condition 1 is satisfied e.g. i can have a schema.xml File in where i can modify to put my Custom Edit/New forms BUT my list is being displayed not the way i want to (like described in Point 2) it is diplayed in rows and columns (no reply button etc...)
- If i create a custom list (from Visual Studio again) based on Discussion Board list template, it is displayed (its Default View) just like i want to (as described in point 2) but in Visual Studio i only have a list instance, i don't have access to its Schema.xml where i can put links to my custom New/Edit forms.

I tried too many things; I tried to provision the Views programmatically just like in this : [Thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114838/custom-sarepoint-lists-forms) but none helped me.

The last thing i tried is to take the desired view from SharePoint Discussion Lists (found its schema.xml in 15 hive) and i tried to integrate in my custom List, but i No relevant results...

So, in summary i need either to be able to import View from List to List or to be able to modify Schema.xml of SharePoint Lists that are based on specific list template (in my case Discussion Board template)

Any help will be welcome